# predis with phpiredis clustering

Tags: php, redis, predis

I'm trying to use redis clusters with predis + phpiredis as I saw that phpiredis improves the performance.

This is my PHP code:

```
    $cluster = [
    'tcp://127.0.0.1:30001',
    'tcp://127.0.0.1:30002',
    'tcp://127.0.0.1:30003',
    'tcp://127.0.0.1:30004',
    'tcp://127.0.0.1:30005',
    'tcp://127.0.0.1:30006',
];  

$client = new Predis\Client($cluster,
    [
    'connections' => [
        'tcp'  => 'Predis\Connection\PhpiredisStreamConnection'
    ],
    ]
);
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Predis\Response\ServerException' with message 'MOVED 6918 127.0.0.1:30002' in /var/www/html/predis-1.0/src/Client.php:365 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/predis-1.0/src/Client.php(330): Predis\Client->onErrorResponse(Object(Predis\Command\StringGet), Object(Predis\Response\Error)) #1 /var/www/html/predis-1.0/src/Client.php(310): Predis\Client->executeCommand(Object(Predis\Command\StringGet)) #2 /var/www/html/redisTests/predis.php(52): Predis\Client->__call('get', Array) #3 /var/www/html/redisTests/predis.php(52): Predis\Client->get('test') #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/predis-1.0/src/Client.php on line 365

Now if i set only the first 2 clusters ips, it works fine. Can someone please explain how come?

Can someone tell me whats wrong? is predis + phpiredis fully support clustering?

Thanks in advance for your help!